# Laravel Eloquent GroupBy statement

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this table and i'm trying to achieve a multiple `groupBy` and `distinct` through Laravel with a sum of duration. Basically, i need to find in table multiple ids passed from controller and then if windows, method and type are the same, sum the duration value.

Here is table structure

```
+-----+---------+--------+----------+------+
| ids | windows | method | duration | type |
+-----+---------+--------+----------+------+
|  1  |    2    |    3   |     5    |   2  |
+-----+---------+--------+----------+------+
|  2  |    2    |    3   |     5    |   2  |
+-----+---------+--------+----------+------+
|  3  |    2    |    3   |     5    |   2  |
+-----+---------+--------+----------+------+
```

and here is the statement that i try to use:

```
$tickets_g = \App\Models\Ticked::whereIn('id', $tickets)
    ->select('categoria', 'tipologia', 'priority', 'durata')
    ->distinct()
    ->GroupBy('categoria')
    ->GroupBy('tipologia')
    ->GroupBy('priority')
    ->sum('durata')
    ->get();
```

Can someone help me to figure out?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed myself this is the correct query if someone stuck in the same issue:

```
  $tickets_g = \App\Models\Ticked::select('support_ticked.*', DB::raw("SUM(support_ticked.durata) as durata_totale"))
->groupBy('support_ticked.tipologia','support_ticked.priority', 'support_ticked.categoria')
->get();
```